# Error while importing a DUMP file

Tags: oracle, import, sqlplus, dump

SQL> impdp Fossil_ARSENAL/Fossil_ARSENAL@ARIF Dumpfile=FOSSIL_PLM_AUG_11.dmp transfo
rm=SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES:N:INDEX REMAP_TABLESPACE=FOSSIL_PLM:Fossil_ARSENAL REMAP_SCH
EMA=FOSSIL_PLM:Fossil_ARSENAL LOGFILE=dp.log;

Error Msg Below:
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "impdp Foss..." - rest of line ignored.

USERNAME : Fossil_ARSENAL
PASSWORD : Fossil_ARSENAL
DataBase Name : ARIF
Dumpfile NAme : FOSSIL_PLM_AUG_11.dmp
TableSpace Name : Fossil_ARSENAL

Comment: A raw error dump with no context isn't particularly helpful. Are there any details you can give us that might help us work out what's happening here?

Answer (score 4):

`impdp` is a separate executable; you call it from your operating system's command line, not from within SQL*Plus. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL801) describes `expdp` and `impdp` as command-line clients.  The command looks reasonable, apart from noot seeming to have a `directory` argument; you're just issuing it in the wrong place.